# Error with Gtk.init in main.js

Tags: javascript, gtk, gnome

I'm following [this tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/unstable/record-collection.js.html.en). But I keep getting this error when I try to run it;

```
    JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was: Error: Expected type utf8 for Argument 'argv' but got type 'number' (nil)
    JS ERROR: !!!     message = '"Expected type utf8 for Argument 'argv' but got type 'number' (nil)"'
    JS ERROR: !!!     fileName = '"main.js"'
    JS ERROR: !!!     lineNumber = '146'
    JS ERROR: !!!     stack = '"@main.js:146
"'
Error: Expected type utf8 for Argument 'argv' but got type 'number' (nil)
```

I'm really not sure what's wrong.. The error occurs on line 146;

> Gtk.init (0, null);

The code used is available [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/unstable/record-collection/record-collection.js).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's a bug. Take a look at this message with the patch: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2012-February/msg10213.html

You should change `Gtk.init(0,null);` by `Gtk.init(null, null);`.

Comment: The message from the commits-list it's about another tutorial, but it's a general bug in the documentation.